# Unable to use lag function correctly in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I have created a table from multiple tables like this:

```
Week | Cid | CustId | L1
10 | 1 | 1 | 2
10 | 2 | 1 | 2
10 | 5 | 1 | 2
10 | 4 | 1 | 1
10 | 3 | 2 | 1
4  | 6 | 1 | 2
4  | 7 | 1 | 2
```

I want the output as:

```
Repeat
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
```

So, basically what I want is for each week, if a person (custid) comes in again with the same L1, then the value in the column `Repeat` should become 1, otherwise 0 ( so like, here, in row 2 & 3, custid 1, came with L1=2 again, so it will get 1 in column "Repeat", however in row 4, custid 1 came with L1=1, so it will get value as ).

By the way, the table isn't ordered (as I've shown).

I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
select t.*,
lag(0, 1, 0) over (partition by week, custid, L1 order by cid) as repeat
from
table;
```

But this is not giving the output and is giving empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `case`, but I would use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by week, custid, l1 order by cid) = 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as repeat
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be computed without Window functions but by a self-join in the following way:

```
SELECT a.week, a.cid, a.custid, a.l1,
       CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS repeat
FROM mytable a NATURAL LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT week, min(cid) AS cid, custid, l1 FROM mytable
      GROUP BY week,custid,l1) b
ORDER BY week DESC, custid, l1 DESC, cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply by using an count(*) as analytic function. No case expression or self join needed. The query is even portable across databases that support analytic functions:

```
SELECT cust.*, least(count(*) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY Week, CustId, L1 ORDER BY Cid
        ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - 1, 1) repeat
FROM cust ORDER BY Week DESC, custId, L1 DESC;
```

Executing the query on your data results in the following output (last row is the repeat row):

```
Week | Cid | CustId | L1 | repeat
10  1   1   2   0
10  2   1   2   1
10  5   1   2   1
10  4   1   1   0
10  3   2   1   0
4   6   1   2   0
4   7   1   2   1
```

Tested on Oracle 11g and PostgreSQL 9.4. Note that the second `ORDER BY` is optional. See [Oracle Language Reference, Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) for more details.